# All map services display pink tiles

Tags: postgis, postgresql, mapserver, imposm, mapcache

I have implemented mapserver in Ubuntu 14.04 with postgresql 9.3, postgis and imposm using [GitHub tutorial](https://github.com/mapserver/mapserver/wiki/Rendering-OSM-data-on-Ubuntu-12.04). After completing the tutorial all map services display pink tiles not map info. i was not encounter with any issues during the tutorial run. any reason to this?

Following screenshots for your reference.

[image]
[image]
[image]

When I check network I saw some errors as follows it shows as bad gate way and internal server error
[image]

here's my basemap makefile and mapcache.xml file

basemap/makefile

```
UNAME := $(shell uname)

ifeq ($(UNAME), Darwin)
SED=sed -i ""
else
SED=sed -i
endif

CPP=gcc -E -x c
#if the preprocessor fails for some reason, try replacing this with "cpp" on linux, or "cpp-4.2" on darwin (not available starting with mountain lion)


OSM_PREFIX=osm_new_
OSM_NAME_COLUMN=name
OSM_SRID=4326
OSM_UNITS=dd
OSM_EXTENT=-180 -90 180 90
OSM_SRID=3857
OSM_UNITS=meters
OSM_DB_CONNECTION=host=localhost dbname=osm user=osm password=osm port=5432
OSM_EXTENT=-20000000 -20000000 20000000 20000000
OSM_WMS_SRS=EPSG:900913 EPSG:4326 EPSG:3857 EPSG:2154 EPSG:310642901 EPSG:4171 EPSG:310024802 EPSG:310915814 EPSG:310486805 EPSG:310702807 EPSG:310700806 EPSG:310547809 EPSG:310706808 EPSG:310642810 EPSG:310642801 EPSG:310642812 EPSG:310032811 EPSG:310642813 EPSG:2986
DEBUG=1
LAYERDEBUG=1
STYLE=google
#can also use google or bing
```

mapcache-osm.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- see the accompanying https://github.com/mapserver/mapcache/blob/master/mapcache.xml.sample for a fully commented configuration file -->
<mapcache>
<cache name="disk" type="disk">
    <base>/home/sithila/osm-demo/mapcache/cache</base> <!-- Change Path here -->
    <symlink_blank/>
</cache>

<source name="osm" type="wms">
    <getmap>
        <params>
            <FORMAT>image/png</FORMAT>
            <LAYERS>default</LAYERS>
            <MAP>/home/sithila/osm-demo/basemaps/osm-google.map</MAP> <!-- Change Path here -->
        </params>
    </getmap>
    <http>
        <url>http://localhost/cgi-bin/mapserv?</url> <!-- Change server here -->
    </http>
</source>
<tileset name="osm">
    <metadata>
        <title>OSM MapServer served map</title>
        <abstract>see https://github.com/mapserver/mapserver/wiki/RenderingOsmDataUbuntuv2</abstract>
    </metadata>
    <source>osm</source>
    <cache>disk</cache>
    <grid>WGS84</grid>
    <grid>g</grid>
    <format>PNG</format>
    <metatile>5 5</metatile>
    <metabuffer>10</metabuffer>
    <expires>10000</expires>
    <auto_expire>86400</auto_expire>  
</tileset>

<default_format>JPEG</default_format>

<service type="wms" enabled="true">
    <full_wms>assemble</full_wms>
    <resample_mode>bilinear</resample_mode>
    <format>JPEG</format>
    <maxsize>4096</maxsize>
</service>

<service type="wmts" enabled="true"/>
<service type="tms" enabled="true"/>
<service type="kml" enabled="true"/>
<service type="gmaps" enabled="true"/>
<service type="ve" enabled="true"/>
<service type="demo" enabled="true"/>

<errors>report</errors>
<lock_dir>/tmp</lock_dir>
</mapcache>
```

In my further troubleshooting i have execute curl command with a url of a pink tile and received as follows.

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no" ?>
<!DOCTYPE ServiceExceptionReport SYSTEM "http://schemas.opengis.net/wms/1.1.1/exception_1_1_1.dtd">
<ServiceExceptionReport version="1.1.1">
<ServiceException>
<![CDATA[
wms request for tileset osm returned an unsupported format:
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>404 Not Found</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Not Found</h1>
<p>The requested URL /cgi-bin/mapserv was not found on this server.</p>
<hr>
<address>Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) Server at localhost Port 80</address>
</body></html>

]]>
</ServiceException>
```

Comment: Look at the network tab of your browser's developer console, ctrl+shift+i in Chrome and FF to see what is being requested. You will likely have some errors in the console too.

Comment: Please don't cross post. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26124917/all-map-services-display-pink-tiles. And provide a bit more information.

Comment: This kind of error is usually due to a problem with a proxy, http://www.checkupdown.com/status/E502.html. Do you have a proxy set up. And do you definitely have a server running on localhost?